# Every time I try to start Tor I get "You configured a non-loopback address ... for SocksPort"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Every time I try to start Tor I get the following response. What to do?

```
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 172.30.1.1:3128 
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [WARN] Could not bind to 172.30.1.1:3128: Cannot assign requested address [WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL ] 
5/9/2018 12:15:14 PM.000 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports. 
5/9/2018 12:15:28 PM.300 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:28 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 172.30.1.1:3128 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [WARN] Could not bind to 172.30.1.1:3128: Cannot assign requested address [WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL ] 
5/9/2018 12:15:33 PM.500 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '172.30.1.1:3128' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 172.30.1.1:3128 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [WARN] Could not bind to 172.30.1.1:3128: Cannot assign requested address [WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL ] 
5/9/2018 12:15:45 PM.500 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the text you posted.

`[WARN] Could not bind to 172.30.1.1:3128: Cannot assign requested address [WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL ]`

First of all, 3128 is not a common socks5 port. It is, however, a common HTTP proxy port. So if your intention is to use Tor's SocksPort as an HTTP Proxy, you're not going to have a good time.

Now, are you sure 172.30.1.1 is even the IP address of the computer you're running Tor on? Because that's the most likely reason for getting that error.